# How to strip the resource pool name from 'vim.ResourcePool:resgroup-151'

Tags: vmware, pyvmomi

The data type is `<class 'pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.vim.ResourcePool'>` and when I return the rp I get `'vim.ResourcePool:resgroup-151'` (with the single quote characters there) but are there any methods that can just return the `resgroup-151`?

Answer (score 0):

return `rp.name`.

**Managed objects** can have both properties and operations.

`<class 'pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.vim.ResourcePool'>` is a managed object and few of it properties are :

```
summary, owner, alarmActionsEnabled, configIssue, configStatus, customValue, declaredAlarmState, disabledMethod, effectiveRole, name, overallStatus, parent, permission, recentTask, tag, triggeredAlarmState
```